# Element chopped off on IE8 only - any takers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

My site http://bit.ly/aokA4I has a search bar on the top right.

You can see it on IE7, FF, Chrome, Safari -- but not on IE8. It gets chopped off.

BTW if you happen to see it on IE8 just refresh the page and it will chop.

If I run IE8 on compatibility mode the search bar becomes visible.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because IE8 is interpreting the nature of its parent container: header_widget_1. The sizing or formatting of this element is causing the `<li>` element to be clipped prematurely. If you have Google Chrome, you can right click the sidebar element you're asking about and choose "Inspect Element". This will show you what the elements are doing.

**Edit:** You also have a sizable horizontal scrollbar in IE7.

**Edit 2:**
You might try altering the height of your `#header` element to be the height you want. Since height is not expressed in the *sidebar* class, this may also be contributing to the problem.

Comment: trying this right now -- any sugg to remove the horizontal bar on IE7?

Comment: @mptorr - not really, I tried to view the source to see if there was any obvious cause, but the source was very complicated in notepad.

Comment: @mptorr - The IE7 scrollbar is pretty intermittent. It looks like something specific to my browser. It is only happening on 1-2 refreshes out of every 10. It is not happening at all on a different computer.

Comment: sorry joel -- i now turned off all sorts of minification and caching so if you have a chance to take a look let me know -- thx!

Comment: alright -- seems to be solved for now by adding height to #header_widget_1 -- thx for your help joel -- let me know if you happen to see it NOT working on your side!